# Install App Blocked by play protect [ Debug APK ] - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, apk, google-play-services

Our application is listed on play store.

I just change my laptop and rebuild the project.Our release key for signing app on play store is also same.But when I create a debug app it provides me this type of alert Install App Blocked by play protect. When I try to create release apk it didn't provide such message. On my old system I didn't face such type of situation for same app and builds.

What can be a issue with new System?Is there any solution I can try from old system such like copy some file and paste in new system? Or generate new keychain file in new system?

Tried Solutions :
Delete Debug.keystore

[image]

Comment: If you have access to your old system or a backup you could extract the debug keystone and use it on your new system. You should find it in the `.android` directory in your home directory.

Comment: @Robert Currently I cannot access my old system.So ultimate way is to generate new but that is something not working. 
If I copy same file from my colleague system then it was not giving me same error.

Comment: I actually have the same issue. When you use some old debug.keystore everything works fine. However if you generate a new one automatically from latest Android studio or via keytool then not recognized app developer warning is displayed. Is there any other workaround? I do not plan to release our internal app to google play and this message is really annoying :)